# How to use TClientDataSet with SQL Server view? (Or alternative)

Tags: sql-server, delphi, delphi-7, tclientdataset

In my form I have `TADOQuery,TDataSetProvider,TClientDataSet,TDataSource,TDBGrid` linked.

AdoQuery  use SQL Server view to query data

`AdoQuery.SQL`:

```
Select * from vu_Name where fld=:fldval
```

Vu_Name:

```
SELECT * FROM  t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.fld1 = t2.fld1
```

in my dbgrid, only columns in table t1 are editable.(only t1 need to update )

What are the possible (fastest) ways to apply updates back to the server?
`ClientDataSet.ApplyUpdates(0); // not working`

Thank you.

Comment: just for interesst, is there a need for TDatasetprovider and TClientdataset or would a disconnected Recordset work for you too?
http://etutorials.org/Programming/mastering+delphi+7/Part+III+Delphi+Database-Oriented+Architectures/Chapter+15+Working+with+ADO/Disconnected+Recordsets/

Comment: Thank you. But I think this is not working when quarry uses view that joint multiple tables to retrieve data.

Comment: You might need TCustomADODataSet(DataSet).Properties['Unique Table'].Value := 'T1';

Comment: 'Unique Table' property is mentioned in msdn but in my project i couldn’t set or read 'unique table' property.  Also i found that Unique Table property only effect to delete operation (not for insert or update). so this is not works for me. But single table operation I agree this is the shortest (disconnected) method. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TDataSetProvider has an event OnGetTableName where you should set the TableName parameter to t1. Thus the provider knows where to store the changed values.

You have to make sure that only fields of t1 are changed as TDataSetProvider will only update one table. Of course you can have different table names for different calls to ApplyUpdates. You can find out about changed fields in the DataSet parameter.

If you want to update more than one table you have to implement OnUpdateData, which gives you all of the freedom with all of the responsibility.

Comment: It works.Thanks. For others who have same problem, this is what I did   
* TDatasetprovider.Updatemod=UpWhereKeyOnly
* [TAdoQuerryKeyFeald].providerflag.pfinkey=true
* OnGetTableName event 
 Tablename:=’T1’;
clientDataset.applyupdates; //works :)